# How can I use while loop that represents split() and also for loop to display selection number for user?

Tags: java

For loop inside While loop not executing at all.
It would work fine without the for loop but had to add the for loop in order to have selection numbers displayed on the screen.(e.g. 1.2.3)

```
try
{
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
    while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] values = line.split(",");
        for (int i = 0; i < zoo.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("Select your choice.\nPress" + (i + 1) + ". (4Legged): " + values[0] + ", (insect):" + values[1] + ", (bird): " + values[2] );
        }
    }
```

The txt file example is:

```
Monkey, Ant, Crow
Cat, Spider, Chicken
Dog, Grasshopper, Magpie
```

The desired output is:
Select your choice.

Press 1. (4Legged): Monkey, (Insect): Ant, (Bird): Crow

Press 2. (4Legged): Cat, (Insect): Spider, (Bird): Chicken

Press 3. (4Legged): Dog, (Insect): Grasshopper, (Bird): Magpie

Comment: You don't need the for loop.  You can declare and initialize a counter variable to 1 before your while loop and increment that variable inside your while loop. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try
{
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
int index = 1;
while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] values = line.split(",");
    
        System.out.println("Select your choice.\nPress" + index + ". (4Legged): " + values[0] + ", (insect):" + values[1] + ", (bird): " + values[2] );
    index ++;
}
```

just use a flag before while loop and use that in your print statement and increment it after printing the values.